# Как создать вертикальную полосу прокрутки с помощью PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Долго искала как создать вертикальную полосу прокрутки, но никак не могу понять
Прошу объясните как это сделать, буду очень благодарна

Comment: Добрый день ! Плохо искали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905227/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-qwidget-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Если в предложенном вам посте не то, что вы искали, опубликуете  [mcve] и объясните лучше что вы хотите сделать.